# Check Contents of Field before using Concat in MySQL Update Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I am updating fields in a database using Concat as follows

```
`fieldName`=concat( `FieldName`, ',NEW DATA')
```

In some instances though, I am trying to create a comma separated list in the field, such as

```
item 1, item 2, item 3
```

But unless I know whether the field is empty before hand, if this is the first entry in the field I cannot avoid having a preceeding, or trailing comma.

```
,item 1, item 2...etc
```

or

```
item 1, item 2, ... etc
```

Is there a way I can determine if the field has a content before I do add data, within the Update statement to avoid having the query the database separately?

... or a better way of making a comma separated list!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a `case` expression like this:

```
update tableName
set columnName = 
  case when LENGTH(columnName) > 1
    then select concat(columnName, ',NEW DATA')
    else select 'NEW DATA' end
```

If the length of the columnName is bigger then 1, there is data in the columName so you can put the comma, otherwise you only put the new data.

Comment: Thanks @aF That looks perfect, but I'm getting Syntax errors.
Trying to update several fields at once
`"UPDATE tableName SET mobile='" & mobile & "', invoiceList = case when len(invoiceList) > 1 then concat(invoiceList, '," & currentInvoiceNumber & "') else '" & currentInvoiceNumber & "' end`
Is the relevant snippet. I keep getting "Check the syntax near len(in "